# Null value adding when creating CSV string in JAVA

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, csv

I am having a form where i getting values from 3 checkbox.  I am getting the values in the servlet as follows,

```
String csvSkills = null;

String[] skills = request.getParameterValues("chkSkills");

for(int i=0; i<skills.length; i++){
    csvSkills   +=  skills[i]+",";
}

System.out.println(csvSkills);
```

OUTPUT:

```
nullPHP,JAVA,MYSQL,
```

Though initially the csvSkills Value is null the null value is displayed.  I tried alot and dont know how to accomplish this. My doubt is How to make csv values without `null` at start?
Hope my question is clear.  Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other answers tell you why there is a null:  you are not initializing your csvSkills string.

The other thing that you should know is that you should be using a StringBuilder for csvSkills rather than a String.  Appending to a String inside a loop is **very** inefficient.  Behind the scenes the compiler is creating a new StringBuilder each time through the loop to concatenate two strings together, and then discarding it.  Each time through the loop the size of the StringBuilder created for that iteration gets larger and larger.  You want to use a single StringBuilder instance for all the appends.

```
StringBuilder  csvSkills = new StringBuilder();
for (String s:  request.getParameterValues("chkSkills")){
    if (csvSkills.length > 0) csvSkills.append(",");
    csvSkills.append(s);
}
return csvSkills.toString();
```

I am the author of free open source Java utilities that handle CSV.  I'd recommend using [the Ostermiller CSV library](http://ostermiller.org/utils/CSV.html) for this. In addition to handling the logic of only appending a comma when needed, it will also handle quoting and escaping in cases where the field you are appending contains quotes or commas.

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
CSVPrinter  csvSkills = new ExcelCsvPrinter(writer);
for (String s:  request.getParameterValues("chkSkills")){
    csvSkills.write(s);
}
return writer.toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Initialize `csvSkills` to an empty string, not `null`.

```
String csvSkills = "";
```

When you concatenate strings with `null` in java, you get the text representation of `null`. Additionally, if you don't want a trailing comma the end of the list, you could conditionally add the comma. Something like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<skills.length; i++){
    if (i > 0) {
        csvSkills += ",";
    }
    csvSkills += skills[i];
}
```

Comment: @JavaBegginer: Is `null` the first value in your `skills` array? Is your form somehow submitting `null` as the first value?

Comment: @Asaph The above is Wrong its going to append , at end like php,mysql,java,

Comment: @JavaBeginner I don't think it's wrong. It will place commas between elements of the array, not at the beginning or end. Try running it. You'll see.

Answer (score 1):

You want to initialize "csvSkills" to "" (empty string) instead of null.

Also consider adding an if statement for whether you add the comma so you don't have a trailing comma at the end.

Comment: I cannot initialize the value to empty

Comment: Why not?  That's the standard idiom for String concatenation.

Comment: Now i did like this String csvSkills = "''"; to and getting the output as ''PHP,JAVA,MYSQL,

Comment: @JavaBeginer you're using " ' ' " instead of " " ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `csvSKills` to an empty String `""`.

```
String csvSkills = "";
```

A better solution would be using `StringBuilder` for concatenating a lot of `String`s:

```
StringBuilder csvSkills = new StringBuilder();

String[] skills = request.getParameterValues("chkSkills");

for (String skill : skills) {
    csvSkills.append(skill).append(",");
}

System.out.println(csvSkills.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add comma only when csvSkills is greater than 0

```
StringBuilder csvSkills = new StringBuilder();

String[] skills = request.getParameterValues("chkSkills");

for (String skill : skills) 
{
   if(csvSkills.length() > 0)
    csvSkills.append(",");

   csvSkills.append(skill);

}
```